# Error in test batch class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, formula, null-pointer

I wrote a batch process that checks a formaula field (date type and based on another Date__c field). If the `PNL_Date__c = Last Month` it checks the `Last_Mnth__c` to `false` and if `PNL_Date__c != Last Month` it checks the `Last_Mnth__c` to `false`.

Unfortunately the test class does not work. When I run the test class it points to this line of code:

```
if(Integer.valueOf(newObjScope.PNL_Date__c.month()) == Integer.valueOF(System.today().month() - 1)){
    newObjScope.Last_Mnth__c = true;
}
```

And gives a `NullPointerException`.

Here is my batch process:

```
global class CashFlowBatchProcess implements Database.Batchable<sobject>{
    global String [] email = new String[] {'VBakanov@bcsprime.com'};
      public String query = 'Select id from Cash_Flow__c';

    //Start Method
    global Database.Querylocator start (Database.BatchableContext BCC) {
      return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, PNL_Date__c FROM Cash_Flow__c]);//Query which will be determine the scope of Records fetching the same
    }

    //Execute method
    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BCC, List<sobject> scope) {
    List<Cash_Flow__c> CFList = new List<Cash_Flow__c>();
    List<Cash_Flow__c> updatedCFList = new List<Cash_Flow__c>();
    for (sObject objScope: scope) { 
        Cash_Flow__c newObjScope = (Cash_Flow__c)objScope ;
        if(Integer.valueOf(newObjScope.PNL_Date__c.month()) == Integer.valueOF(System.today().month() - 1)){
            newObjScope.Last_Mnth__c = true;
        }
        else if (Integer.valueOf(newObjScope.PNL_Date__c.month()) != Integer.valueOF(System.today().month() - 1)){
            newObjScope.Last_Mnth__c = false; 
        }
        updatedCFList.add(newObjScope);
        System.debug('Value of UpdatedCFList'+updatedCFList);
    } 
        if (updatedCFList != null && updatedCFList.size()>0) {
            Database.update(updatedCFList); System.debug('List Size '+updatedCFList.size());
        }
    }

     //Finish Method
     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BCC){

    }
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
@isTest
class TestCashFlowBatchProcess {

    static testmethod void testBatchCash() {

       Account acc = new Account();
       acc.Name = 'Test Account';
       insert acc; 

       Account acc2 = new Account();
       acc2.Name = 'Test Technical';
       insert acc2; 

    List<Cash_Flow__c> st=new List<Cash_Flow__c>(); 
        for(integer i = 0;  i < 1; i++){
            Cash_Flow__c cf = new Cash_Flow__c();
                cf.Account__c = acc.Id;
                cf.RecordTypeId = '012b0000000UOay';
                cf.Date__c = system.today();
                cf.CurrencyIsoCode = 'RUB';
                cf.Last_Mnth__c = true;
                cf.Amount__c = 4;
            st.add(cf);
        }
        insert st;

    Test.startTest();        
        Database.BatchableContext BCC;
        CashFlowBatchProcess obj=new CashFlowBatchProcess();
        obj.query = 'Select id From Cash_Flow__c Where Amount__c = 4 Limit 100';
        obj.start(BCC);
        obj.execute(BCC, st);
        obj.finish(BCC);

        System.assertEquals(1, Database.query(obj.query).size() );
    Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

PNL_Date__c formula:

```
IF(
    RecordType.Name = 'Revenue' && DAY(Date__c) < 27,
    Date(
        IF(Month(Date__c)=1, YEAR(Date__c)-1, YEAR(Date__c)),
        IF(Month(Date__c)=1, 12, Month(Date__c) - 1),
        DAY(Date__c)
    ), Date__c
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use system.debug and check the value of PNL_Date__c before this line:

if(Integer.valueOf(newObjScope.PNL_Date__c.month()) == Integer.valueOF(System.today().month() - 1)){

Comment: Also, please show me the formula you are putting in PNL_Date__c field

Comment: I´m agree with Abhijeet, either newObjScope or PNL_Date__c should be null, but the most posible is PNL_Date__c.

Comment: @Abhijeet fine I have null in the all fields : DEBUG|PNL_Date =nullDate__c =null. But i Don't understand why it is null? In the test class i define the value of the field Date__c and RecordTypeId.

Comment: @Abhijeet added the formula of PNL_Date__c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get It!

Formula will not be evalueates if it was not been returned by SOQL query. Formula evaluates only when SOQL is runned.

My code below:

```
global class CashFlowBatchProcess implements Database.Batchable<sobject>{
global String [] email = new String[] {'VBakanov@bcsprime.com'};
  public String query = 'Select id, PNL_Date__c from Cash_Flow__c';

//Start Method
global Database.Querylocator start (Database.BatchableContext BCC) {
  return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, PNL_Date__c FROM Cash_Flow__c WHERE PNL_Date__c != NULL]);//Query which will be determine the scope of Records fetching the same
}

//Execute method
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BCC, List<sobject> scope) {
List<Cash_Flow__c> CFList = new List<Cash_Flow__c>();
List<Cash_Flow__c> updatedCFList = new List<Cash_Flow__c>();

//This is SOQL Query that returned the formula value:
Cash_Flow__c CaF = [Select ID, PNL_Date__c from Cash_Flow__c];
for (sObject objScope: scope) { 
    Cash_Flow__c newObjScope = (Cash_Flow__c)objScope ;

    system.debug('PNL_Date ='+newObjScope.PNL_Date__c+'Date__c ='+newObjScope.PNL_Date__c);

    if(Integer.valueOf(CaF.PNL_Date__c.month()) == Integer.valueOF(System.today().month() - 1)){
        newObjScope.Last_Mnth__c = true;            
    }
    else if (Integer.valueOf(CaF.PNL_Date__c.month()) != Integer.valueOF(System.today().month() - 1)){
        newObjScope.Last_Mnth__c = false; 
    }
    updatedCFList.add(newObjScope);
    System.debug('Value of UpdatedCFList'+updatedCFList);
} 
    if (updatedCFList != null && updatedCFList.size()>0) {
        Database.update(updatedCFList); System.debug('List Size '+updatedCFList.size());
    }
}

//Finish Method
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BCC){

}
}
```